# copy a folder with it's content to a remote VM

Tags: vmware, powercli

I need your help with a script that i am building.I need it to:`
To find a VM and see if it is turned off or on.
If it is off then turn it on and copy a folder with the content to replace the old folder in the VM machine.

$vmName = 'Target'
$folderName = 'C:\Folder'

Get-VM -Name $vmName | where{$_.PowerState -ne 'PoweredOn'} | Start-VM -Confirm:$false
sleep 30

Copy-VMGuestFile  -LocalToGuest -Source $folderName -Destination $folderName -Confirm:$false

My problem is that the folder and its content is copy to the destination but it will not replace the folder and its content from the destination VM.

Regrades,

Michel Vaillancourt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `-Force` clobbers existing files on the target, but will not mirror the source contents, at least with PowerCLI 5.8 R1. So files that exist on target but not source before the copy will remain on the target after the copy. Not sure if this is by design. `Invoke-VMScript` could delete the target folder before `Copy-VMGuestFile` runs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Robocopy or some other tool after the VM is up?

1- Start-VM, wait 1 or 2 minutes.
2- Loop until "Test-Path $folderName" is true.
3- Copy folder.